# Programmatic access to the iOS status bar?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uistatusbar

I'm trying to reproduce something that an iPad app called Mailbox is doing. The app is somehow able to control the status bar in ways I can't figure out. [The follow picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWBtc.png) shows an app state where the main screen panel is shifted to the right, and somehow the status bar has moved off to the right as well:

[image]

[The follow picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywDcH.png) shows the app when it's temporarily replaced the status bar with a simple label that contains custom text ("Mailbox in sync"). When you pull the messages list to refresh, it appears that the main status bar slides up out of site and then this custom label slides down in its place:

[image]

Anybody know how this is being done?

Comment: The first picture is reproducible using [MSDynamicsDrawerViewController](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSDynamicsDrawerViewController/) - perhaps the code there might help?

Comment: @AaronBrager: thanks, that answer has exactly what I'm looking for. I figured they were hacking this with a screenshot.

Comment: No problem.  I don't like this approach because the time / signal strength / battery stop updating, which can be confusing / annoying to users.

Comment: They probably poll every few seconds and take a fresh screenshot of the status bar. I don't like it either, and I'm surprised Apple didn't establish a no-mucking-with-the-statusbar rule.